# jQuery selectors of nested ul

Tags: jquery, html, nested, html-lists

I'm having issues figuring out a specific selector of a nested unordered list's.

How can I select the parent li's that do NOT eventually have a child that contain's the word "test1"..

So in this example -> it would give me Parent Cat 1, Parent Cat 2, and Parent Cat 4. Because Parent Cat 3 eventually has a li that contains "test1"

```
<ul>
<li>Parent Cat 1</li>
<li>Parent Cat 2</li>
<li>Parent Cat 3
    <ul>
        <li >SubCat1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>test1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li >SubCat2
            <ul>
                <li >test2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Parent Cat 4</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like this should work:

```
$('li:not(li li):not(:has(:contains("test1")))')
```

If you can directly target the root `ul` somehow and don't care whether the `test1` is inside a child or the element itself, you can simplify the selector to:

```
$('#root > li:not(:contains("test1"))')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - I understand what your doing here, although I just tested and nothing is coming back from this. Cant figure out whats wrong though.

jQuery('li:not(li li):not(:has(:contains("test1")))')

Comment: Yes you're very right it does - sorry not sure why it wasn't working for me in firebug. Thank you!